# '=': left operand must be l-value - Looking to use an Array within C Language

Tags: c

I am trying to get the user to input specific values into an array, and get "Total" back of all the integers. Here are the specific parameters.

- Main() asks the user to enter the size of the array
- Main() asks the user to enter the random values
- Main() calls other worker functions and displays the results
- Worker functions should match these specs:

o   getTotalAndAverage()
takes int array and size, total and average by reference - returns a void

I'm only trying to do the total piece as of now, just to understand what I'm executing incorrectly. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void getTotalandAvg(int array1[], int size, int* tot, int* avg);


int main() {
    int size, input, avg;
    int total;
    int array1[10000];
    printf("Please Enter a Size: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &size);

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("Please Enter Value: ");
        scanf_s("%d", &input);
        array1[i] = input;
    }
    getTotalandAvg(array1, size, &total, &avg);
    printf("%d", total);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void getTotalandAvg(int array1[], int size, int* tot, int* avg) {
    int input = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
         array1[i] + input = *tot;
    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: That is an unfriendly comment. He is referring to `array1[i] + input = *tot`; That is not the correct synthatx.

Comment: You cannot assign a new value to things that are conceptually pure values. The abstract concept of the number "3" cannot be changed to have the value of the abstract concept of the number "5" without seriously compromising the fabric of thought and logic. Edit: This includes constructs like `1 + 2 = 5;`, which reduce to `3 = 5;` and are thus equally meaningless.

Comment: Wrote the line 'array1[i] + input = *tot;' incorrectly my fault. Wrote it so that the '*tot' to equal the operation. '*tot = *tot + array1[i];'

Comment: That change is a step in the right direction. Something else you should keep in mind when working with C is that local variables are not automatically initialized to 0. In other words, your "avg" and "total" variables have random garbage in them. It might be 0, but you can't count on it. It's good practice to initialize all variables.

Otherwise, how does your code look with the new change? Can you provide a specific input, the result, and what you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C assignment operator, `=`, assigns the result obtained by evaluating its right-hand operand to the *object* designated by its left-hand operand.  It follows that the expression serving as its left-hand operand must in fact designate an object -- *i.e.* it must identify storage, which is what it means to be an "lvalue".  In fact, that term comes from exactly this requirement: the 'l' is short for "left", as in the left operand of an assignment expression.

The problematic statement is this one:

```
            array1[i] + input = *tot;
```

The left-hand operand of `=` is `array1[i] + input`, which is a valid expression, but *not* an lvalue.  You cannot assign to it, just like you cannot assign to `1 + 2` or `x * y`.

It's unclear what you actually want to do here, but from the function name I'd guess that you want either

```
            input += array1[i];
```

or

```
            *tot += array1[i];
```

or both.

Comment: Yes, thanks! I figured it out but that is an awesome explanation that definitely solidifies my understanding. I appreciate your answer greatly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with this code.

```
array1[i] + input = *tot;
```

The problem with it is that `array1[i] + input` is not an *lvalue*, meaning that the left hand side of the `=` isn't an object that can store the value of the right hand side. It's just one of the numbers from the array, added to another number. That's what caused the error you were getting.

... anyway, the task is quite simple if the task is done in two separate stages.

1. Add up the values in the array to get the total
2. Divide the total by the number of items to get the average

Here's how I would do that.

```
void getTotalandAvg(int arr[], int siz, int* tot, int* avg)
{
    // count the total of all values
    int total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < siz; i++)
    {
         total += arr[i];
    }

    // store the total
    *tot = total;
    // calculate and store the average
    *avg = total / siz;
}
```

Note that the average is going to be rounded down to an integer value. If you prefer it to be rounded up, you could calculate the average using the expression `(total+(siz-1))/siz` instead.
Note, too, that I deliberately altered the names of the variables so that there's no risk of confusing local variables and parameters from global variables or variables that are local to the calling function. I've found that this avoids a lot of potential grief in the long run.

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you so much for the input this really helped simplify the problem and explain it. Well done and thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

I want to add something @john-bulliger answer. Because the array name also l value expressin, but you can’t use like left operand of assignment.
I  have used & operator for specifing value type of expression. If you used expression with & operator and there is no mistake, this expression must be l value expression. Otherwise expression must be r value